# How to serve a remote file as a download with CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, download, ftp, cakephp-3.x

I would like to download file from remote NAS server, I am not able to force download to client. I am using this function:

```
    public function download(){
    // Set IP and port
    define("FTP_CONNECT_IP", "xxx");
    define("CONNECT_PORT", "21");

    // Set username and password
    define("FTP_LOGIN_USER", "username");
    define("FTP_LOGIN_PASS", "password");
    $remote_file = 'ftp://' . FTP_LOGIN_USER . ':' . FTP_LOGIN_PASS . '@' . FTP_CONNECT_IP . '/' .'PathToFile.avi';
    $response = $this->response->withFile($remote_file,['download' => true]);
    return  $response;

    }
```

It starts read something but never browser asks me for download. Please What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `Response::withFile()` for remote files, it only works with local files.

If you want to serve remote files, then you either have to temporarily store them on your server, or build a proper download response on your own, using for example CakePHPs callback stream for the response body to output the data manually.

Here's a quick example (doesn't support range requests):

```
return $this->response
    ->withType(pathinfo($remote_file, \PATHINFO_EXTENSION))
    ->withDownload(basename($remote_file))
    ->withLength(filesize($remote_file))
    ->withBody(new \Cake\Http\CallbackStream(function () use ($remote_file) {
        ob_end_flush();
        ob_implicit_flush();
        readfile($remote_file);
    }));
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Request & Response Objects > Response > Setting the Body](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#setting-the-body)**